# Lowercase last name bibliography and citation with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to make a simple switch from uppercase last names (in citations and in references). So far neither `mkbibnamefamily` nor `DeclareFieldFormat` work. There are so many tweaks and options in the `cbx` [file](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/blob/master/latex/cbx/abnt.cbx) that none of the changes seem to have any effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=abnt,
maxcitenames=2,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\addbibresource{nome.bib}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\MakeLowercase{#1}}% doesn't work


\begin{filecontents}{nome.bib}

@book{fulano,
    author = {Fulano de Tal},
    title = {Observação de pássaros como prática mística},
    publisher = {Editora Capivara},
    date = {2022},
    edition = {3},
    location = {Jaboticabal}
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\cite{fulano}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-abnt` uses a very roundabout way to redefine the name formats. Family names are ultimately typeset with `\UpperOrSC` in the bibliography and `\UpperOrSCCite` in citations, so the quickest way is to redefine those macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=abnt,
maxcitenames=2,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\UpperOrSC}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\UpperOrSCCite}[1]{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson; Ryde, 1998)//Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, v. 19, n. 4, p. 377–395, 1998.]

Comment: You're right. I was struggling to find which command defined which feature in the meandering nested (re)definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The `biblatex-abnt` package also has normal capitalization macros that can replace the uppercase variant while maintaining the small caps functionality:

```latex
\let\UpperOrSC\NormalOrSC
\let\UpperOrSCCite\NormalOrSCCite
```